# Is having an arbitrary open set Vx contained in a set B for each x in B enough to show that B is open?

Tags: general-topology

I recently saw the following proof to show that the set of accumulation points is closed in Hausdorff spaces:

x∈X∖A′→ ∃ U⊆X  s.t. x∈U, U is open and U∩A⊆{x}
Now by Hausdorff condition, {x} is closed and hence (X∖{x})∩U=U∖{x} is open as well.

Let y∈U if y≠x then y∈U∖{x} and U∖{x}∩A=∅

so y∈X∖A′ hence, as x∈X∖A′,

U⊆X∖A′ and X∖A′ is open, giving the result.

I am confused by how the last two lines of this proof imply that X∖A′ is open.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let $U_x$ be such a set around $x$. Then $X\setminus A' = \bigcup_{x\in X\setminus A'} U_x$ is open because [any union of open sets in a topological space is open](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Union_of_Open_Sets_is_Open).

Comment: Also, to give credit where credit is due, this proof comes verbatim from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243235/set-of-accumulation-points-is-closed-in-hausdorff-spaces).

Comment: Oh ok, thank you!

Comment: I find this proof confusing. In particular if $U$ is open and $A\cap U\subset \{x\},$ it is irrelevant that $U$ \ $\{x\}$ is open.  Let $\Bbb F$ be the set of all open subsets of $X $ such that $U\in\Bbb F$ iff  $U\cap A$ has at most 1 member. Then $W=\bigcup\Bbb F$  is open and $W\supseteq X$ \ $A'$.... Now if $y\in X$ \ $W$ and if $V$ is any open set containing $y$ then  $A\cap V$ has at least 2 members $a,a'$(otherwise $y\in V\in \Bbb F,$ making $y\in\bigcup F=W$),... and $y$ is not equal to both $a$ and $a'$ so $(V\cap A)$ \ $\{y\}\ne\emptyset$.... so $y\in A'.$ So $W\subseteq X$ \ $A'$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a set $A$ is open iff for every $X \in A$ there is an open subset $O(x)$ so that $x \in O(x) \subseteq A$. This means that all points of $A$ are interior points (some texts use this as a definition), and in another way we see that $A=\bigcup \{O(x): x \in A\}$ is open as a union of open sets.